# npm fails to install depencies

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/BishopFox/unredacter) from GitHub and I have to install the dependencies for it. When I run "npm install" it gives me the following error.

```html
Last login: Sat Feb 19 20:41:00 on ttys000
jakob@Jakobs-MacBook-Air ~ % cd Desktop/unredacter 
jakob@Jakobs-MacBook-Air unredacter % npm install
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.2.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/jakob/Desktop/unredacter/node_modules/electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found) for https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.4.4/electron-v9.4.4-darwin-arm64.zip
npm ERR!     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/jakob/Desktop/unredacter/node_modules/got/source/as-stream.js:35:24)
npm ERR!     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR!     at module.exports (/Users/jakob/Desktop/unredacter/node_modules/got/source/get-response.js:22:10)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.handleResponse (/Users/jakob/Desktop/unredacter/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:155:5)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:538:35)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/Users/jakob/Desktop/unredacter/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/source/index.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:618:27)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:482:22)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jakob/.npm/_logs/2022-02-19T19_41_32_484Z-debug-0.log
jakob@Jakobs-MacBook-Air unredacter %
```

So it fails to download Electron. I'm using an Apple M1. Makes sense that it doesn't install since since it tries to install Electron v.9.4.4 which didn't release for ARM. How can I tell it to install a newer Electron version and proceed with the other dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have cloned the repo you can run

```
npm install electron@latest --save-dev
```

this will update the package in the dev-dependencies property of the `package.json` which you can check to verify it has been updated to the latest version